# Connecting PHP to Cloud MYSQL Google Apps

Tags: php, cloud

I am trying to connect my google app to a google cloud SQL instance, I have followed all the documentation and have read every page here I can find but no luck so far.

I am connecting using this -

```
<?php
$host = ":/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>";
$user = "root";
$password = " ";
$datbase = "cloudbooks";
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($datbase);
?>
```

The error I am getting is

```
Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: .. why dont you just use the normal, hostname, user and password provided to you? There is nothing special about "cloud MySQL" its still just MySQL.. Also do not yse `mysql_` its deprecated.. At least use `mysqli_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's last.. Do not use `mysql_` instead use `mysqli_` for all the reasons on this you can check this : [Stackoverflow mysql_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Moving on from that, there is no reason you should think of connecting to a MySQL server any different just because of how its hosted. Cloud is a wonderfull *Buzz* word.. But its nothing new, its still just a host.

So you can use the following in your connection construction.

```
$host = "hostname // IP";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$datbase = "your_database";
```

There is actually some documentation also on this : [google 'cloud' MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client)